# How to get ID from url for Put route and Delete

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, tornado

I am trying to put all crud methods under one handler class in **python Tornado** framework. `Post()` and `get()` works, but for some reason *carId* cannot be defined. What is one way I can pass the id of the api endpoint to the method. 
endpoint for put and delete: `api/cars/1`

> Error: TypeError: put() missing 1 required positional argument: 
>   'carId' ERROR:tornado.access:500 PUT /api/cars/1 (::1) 0.50ms

Methods:

```
    # Delete method that deletes data specified by HTTP client from database
    def delete(self, carId):

        try:
            data = json.loads(self.request.body)
            print(data)
            print("Deleting Car")
            id = data["id"]
            if not carId:
                return self.write({"success": False})
            if not len(id):
                return self.write({"success": False})
            c.execute(
                "DELETE FROM cars WHERE id=?",(carId))
            self.write({"success": 200})
        except:
            self.write({"success": False})
        conn.commit()

    # Put route to edit an entity in DB.
    def put(self, carId):

        try:
            data = json.loads(self.request.body)
            print(data)
            print("Updating Cars table")
            id = data["id"]
            make = data["make"]
            model = data["model"]
            if not make or not model or not carId:
                return self.write({"success": False})
            if not len(make) or not len(model):
                return self.write({"success": False})
            c.execute(
                "UPDATE cars SET make=?, model=? WHERE id=?",(make, model, id))
            self.write({"success": 200})
        except:
            self.write({"success": False})
        conn.commit()


def verifyDatabase():
    try:
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM cars')
        print('Table already exists')
    except:
        print('Creating table \'cars\'')
        c.execute('CREATE TABLE cars (\
            id integer primary key,\
            make text,\
            model text)')
        print('Successfully created table \'cars\'')
    conn.commit()

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/api/cars/?", CarHandler),
            (r"/api/cars/[0-9]/?", CarHandler)
        ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)

def main():

    # Verify the database exists and has the correct layout
    verifyDatabase()

    app = Application()
    app.listen(80)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
    conn.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try commenting the `(r"/api/cars/?", CarHandler),` and changing next line to `(r"/api/cars/([0-9])/.*", CarHandler)`.

Comment: Why do you have two urls for `CarHandler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a *capturing group* in the regular expression to tell Tornado what parts to pass to your methods. Put parentheses around the part corresponding to `carId`:

```
 (r"/api/cars/([0-9])/?", CarHandler)
```

Note that `carId` will be passed as a string, so you may need to convert it with `carId = int(carId)`. (Also, unless your car IDs will only ever be single digits, you probably want `([0-9]+)` instead)

Answer (score 0):

**Explaining the error**:
This route `(r"/api/cars/?", CarHandler)` points to CarHandler but it is passing no argument to handler's methods. I believe get and post method are defined this way: `def get(self):`, so they really do not need any argument; On the other hand, put and delete methods are defined as `def put(self, carId):`, so they need to get an argument. For this reason you got the error:
`Error: TypeError: put() missing 1 required positional argument:` The same way, `(r"/api/cars/[0-9]/?", CarHandler)` is passing no argument too.

**Fixing the route error**:
First, as explained by another member, you need to fix `(r"/api/cars/[0-9]/?", CarHandler)` to pass an argument to your methods. You can do it just typing `(` and `)` in your route. It should be like this: `(r"/api/cars/([0-9])/?", CarHandler)`.

**Fixing the method definition error**: 
You can see that even you doing what I said, you probably are still getting the same error. The problem is that all routes are pointed to all methods in a handler. So the handler's methods are supposed to have the same method signature or they should be able to be called all the same way.

This point is a little tricky. PUT and DELETE methods expect getting a *carId*, but not all routes are passing a *carId* as argument (`(r"/api/cars/?", CarHandler)` isn't). This route call methods this way: `self.method()`; it will work to `self.get()` or `self.post()`, but not to put or delete, once they are expecting an argument. You can fix it splitting your handler in two or changing your method definition to:

```
def delete(self, carId=None):
    ...

def put(self, carId=None):
    ...
```

And adding some logic validation as `if carId is None: return`